# How to set up natural lens distortion?

Tags: rendering, camera

I want to introduce distortion into my render, but I would like to introduce "natural optical distortion", i.e. the distortion of the default lens.
Do you know how to do this in Blender?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried the *lens distortion* node already: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/distort/lens_distortion.html ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Yes I tried the lens distortion but it is not what I would like.
Thanks, brockmann, maybe this question can solve mine.

Comment: Yep, that's the more accurate way.